# JavaScript: Catch errors in async function and stop the rest of the function if there are any

Tags: javascript, async-await

EDIT: ANSWER BELOW

I'm making my first JavaScript project and decided to make a simple weather app. It fetches weather data of a city you put in from the openweathermap.org api and displays it in a table. I firstly made it using fetch() and .then. I then learned about async functions and the await keyword. After converting the script to an asynchronous function, I came across a problem. If the first city you enter isn't a real city (an error is catched while fetching the api), the warning message appears, BUT the table also appears because the rest of the function still executes.
So my question is: how can I stop the async function if any errors are catched?

Here's the website: https://lorenzo3117.github.io/weather-app/

Here's the code:

```
// Launch weather() function and catch any errors with the api request and display the warning message if there are any errors
function main() {
    weather().catch(error => {
        document.querySelector("#warningMessage").style.display = "block";
        console.log(error);
    });
}

// Main function
async function weather() {

    // Take city from input and reset input field
    var city = document.querySelector("#cityInput").value;
    document.querySelector("#cityInput").value = "";

    // Get api response and make it into a Json
    const apiResponse = await fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&appid=<apiKey>&units=metric");
    const jsonData = await apiResponse.json();

    // Removes warning message
    document.querySelector("#warningMessage").style.display = "none";

    // Puts the Json into an array and launches createTable function
    var arrayJson = [jsonData];
    createTable(document.querySelector("#table"), arrayJson);

    // Function to create the table
    function createTable(table, data) {
        // Makes the table visible
        document.querySelector("#table").style.display = "block";

        // Goes through the array and makes the rows for the table
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let rowData = data[i];
            var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

            // This var exists to make the first letter capitalized without making a gigantic line (see insertCell(3), line 53)
            // Could be made into a function if needed
            var weatherDescription = rowData.weather[0].description;

            // Take latitude and longitude for google maps link
            var lat = rowData.coord.lat;
            var long = rowData.coord.lon;
            // Make an a-tag for link to google maps
            var mapLink = document.createElement("a");
            mapLink.innerHTML = "Link";
            mapLink.target = "_blank";
            mapLink.href = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + lat + "," + long;

            // Making rows in table
            row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = rowData.name + ", " + rowData.sys.country;
            row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = rowData.main.temp + " °C";
            row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = rowData.main.humidity + "%";
            row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = weatherDescription.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + weatherDescription.slice(1);
            row.insertCell(4).appendChild(mapLink); // appendChild for anchor tag because innerHTML only works with text
        }
    }
```

And the repo: https://github.com/lorenzo3117/weather-app

Thank you

Comment: what actually happens if the city doesn't exist? which part of the weather function throws an error? and what is the error that is logged to the console in your `.catch`?

Comment: @JaromandaX if the city doesn't exist, the api gives a 404 error. It also gives an error while making the table, because the used json object don't exist (which is normal because the api doesn't answer the right json with the data) and that's what I want to avoid because it also makes the table visible.

Comment: @LorenzoCatalano how can I stop the async function if any errors are catched? ... it will stop automatically when it catches errors

Comment: Don't call createTable if jsonData is undefined/wrong format?

Comment: @James Thanks for your answer but I found the problem and posted it below. I just can't mark it as an answer for two days. I edited the question though. Have a good day.

Comment: You'll need to check `apiResponse` for he repsonse status (e.g. is it 200 OK, or 404 or something else) - fetch doesn't throw an error on a 404

Comment: @JaromandaX I found out what the problem was and posted it below, I just can't mark it as answered yet. Tldr: the error didn't come from the api, it still sends a (different) json, the error came from trying to grab weather data from the json (which don't exist because the fetched json doesn't have the right content because the city doesn't exist). This happens after the table is set visible. Putton the line that makes the table visible after the createTable function (where the error happen) solved it. Thanks for the help and have a good day.

Comment: Lorenzo you're getting some good suggestions here and while you may have "fixed" your problem your way, there are a lot of things you could be doing better.  For example, when you receive the json back, check if it contains a message indicating that your search failed, and abort at that point.  Don't build a table full of error messages and just "not show it".

Comment: @LorenzoCatalano - I know all that, which is why I suggested to check for the http response to see if it's 200 or not

Comment: @James Thank you so much for pointing this out to me, I would have never thought about this (which could have been a big problem in a bigger project). I just updated my answer with an if else statement which checks if the json is the correct one. Again, thank you! Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the error catched isn't an error with the api itself because the api still sends a json, but the error is catched while trying to read a certain object from the json (which doesn't exist because the json isn't a normal one with weather data). Therefore the function stops far later than expected, after the table was made visible.

I just put the line that made the table visible after the function that creates the table (after where the real error occurs). Also thanks @Dadboz for the try catch method which made the code even more compact. I also added an if else to check if the json file is the correct one so unnecessary code doesn't get executed. Thanks @James for pointing this out to me.

Here's the final code:

```
// Main function
async function weather() {
    try {
        // Take city from input and reset input field
        var city = document.querySelector("#cityInput").value;
        document.querySelector("#cityInput").value = "";

        // Get api response and make it into a Json
        const apiResponse = await fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&appid=<apiKey>&units=metric");
        const jsonData = await apiResponse.json();

        if (jsonData.message == "city not found") {
            document.querySelector("#warningMessage").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            // Removes warning message
            document.querySelector("#warningMessage").style.display = "none";

            // Puts the Json into an array and launches updateTable function
            var arrayJson = [jsonData];
            updateTable(document.querySelector("#table"), arrayJson);         
        }
    }

    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

// Function to update the table
function updateTable(table, data) {

    // Goes through the array and makes the rows for the table
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let rowData = data[i];
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);

        // This var exists to make the first letter capitalized without making a gigantic line (see insertCell(3), line 53)
        // Could be made into a function if needed
        var weatherDescription = rowData.weather[0].description;

        // Take latitude and longitude for google maps link
        var lat = rowData.coord.lat;
        var long = rowData.coord.lon;
        // Make an a-tag for link to google maps
        var mapLink = document.createElement("a");
        mapLink.innerHTML = "Link";
        mapLink.target = "_blank";
        mapLink.href = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + lat + "," + long;

        // Making rows in table
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = rowData.name + ", " + rowData.sys.country;
        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = rowData.main.temp + " °C";
        row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = rowData.main.humidity + "%";
        row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = weatherDescription.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + weatherDescription.slice(1);
        row.insertCell(4).appendChild(mapLink); // appendChild for anchor tag because innerHTML only works with text
    }

    // Makes the table visible
    document.querySelector("#table").style.display = "block"; 
}
```

Thanks everyone for your answers, have a good day!

Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
async function weather() {
  try {
     const apiResponse = await fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&appid=02587cc48685af80ea225c1601e4f792&units=metric");
  } catch(err) {
     alert(err); // TypeError: failed to fetch
     return;
   } 
}

 weather();
```